# JS не грузится JSON с одного сайта, с другого грузится

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

Имеется такой код:

```
function getJSON(url) {
        var resp ;
        var xmlHttp ;

        resp  = '' ;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if(xmlHttp != null)
        {
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
            xmlHttp.send( null );
            resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }

        return resp ;
    }

var gjson ;
gjson = getJSON('https://gpsfront.aliexpress.com/getRecommendingResults.do?offset=1&postback=8fa025df-0612-4a7f-9901-5820a67473e1&widgetId=7237617') ;

alert(gjson);
alert("");
```

Когда в url передается JSON c cайта **https://soundcloud.com/oembedformat=json&height=300&url=https://soundcloud.com/giorgiomartini**, то всё работает и ответ отображается в алерт.
Однако, когда url -  **https://gpsfront.aliexpress.com/getRecommendingResults.do?offset=1&postback=8fa025df-0612-4a7f-9901-5820a67473e1&widgetId=7237617**
то тогда скрипт не работает, при чем JSON отдается валидный, в асинхронном коде - та же проблема, в чём может быть причина?

Еще вопрос, как можно скачать HTML-страницу чужого сайта в переменную JS?Php и сторонние серверы не канают, так как это я считаю не продуктивно, расточительно во всём и равно изобретению велосипеда, фреймворки тоже, через загрузку в локальную систему файла, через расширения браузера тоже такие себе способы.Должен быть способ через iframe, script src или может какие-либо современные новые функции?

Comment: CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: другой сайт выдает данные и никакого CORSа не надо и как я на чужой сайт помещу разрешение?

Comment: @Paradise никак. В жтом смысл корс, либо сайт разрешает доступ с других доменом, либо нет и делает это именно владелец сайта, а не любой желающий его использовать.

Comment: @Paradise, проще говоря - суть CORS как раз в предотвращении воровства контента/данных посторонними. Это не ошибка и не проблема, а вполне ожидаемый результат работы реализации данной технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы сделать кросс-доменный запрос, на сайте к которому идет запрос, в хедерах ответа должен быть прописан `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

В вашем случае придется делать запрос с вашего сервера и подгружать данные уже с него, конечно если это допустимо в вашем случае.

Из источника выше:

> Если Access-Control-Allow-Origin нет, то браузер считает, что разрешение не получено, и завершает запрос с ошибкой.